# Meaning of "Hostages to Providence"

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I read this quote recently from businessman Conrad Black, in [a newspaper interview](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/2/8629de60-273d-11e2-9863-00144feabdc0.html#axzz2bx1kORwy) published in the *Financial Times*. How should it be interpreted?

> “I was a bit insouciant. While my conduct certainly did not stray into illegality, as my – and I don’t doubt it, your – ancestors would say, I was in the boldness of my muse **giving hostages to providence** and it did cause me great inconvenience.”

Comment: I don't know why this has attracted down-votes as well as close-votes. But I really like to know the meaning.

Comment: I don't understand either, why this question was closed. I would really like to know, what exactly would make this question too specific, to be helpful for other. I personally would also like to know, what it actually means.

Comment: It's a metaphor, and as such unlikely to be of particular use to others. On the other hand, I don't understand it either, and I'm pretty sure analysis of how that works would help me understand more than this specific one...

Comment: The thing is, this question doesn't give enough context to interpret this quote, and any time you ask for an interpretation, you will almost by definition get differing and opposing views, and that is not the point of ELL as I understand it. We are here to give factual, evidence based responses regarding learning the English language, not to try and interpret vague quotes that may confuse even a native English speaker.

Comment: I've come across the phrase *hostages to fortune*, but I can't see how it makes sense in this context. (A bit more context would help.)

Comment: This is a question that could be answered by looking in a dictionary.  The meanings of Providence include God or divine guidance.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/providence

Comment: The phrase “hostage to providence” was used by [Sarah Tytler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Tytler) in *[A Houseful of Girls](http://archive.org/stream/ahousefulofgirls20081gut/20081-8.txt)* (chapter XXIII, second paragraph). I don't know whether that's what Black was quoting, nor what it means.

Answer (score 3):

In this context it means the subject took actions that might, given enough bad luck, turn out to his considerable disadvantage later. Something your enemies or opponents can use against you if they start looking for some leverage against you; some action that once discovered and made public could ruin your reputation; some risky investment, that could put you in debts and is difficult to get out of; a person you made your enemy, who might get into position to hurt you eventually; the providence in this case is the blind fate, or a higher power way beyond your control, and the hostage is something that is important to you and can be destroyed at the whim of the one holding it. You either fight dearly to restore safety of that hostage, or you risk losing it.

In the particular text it's actions of questionable morality, ones that "did not stray into illegality" but "caused great inconvenience" - actions damaging reputation, or letting the opponents ask uncomfortable questions; things that won't get you in prison themselves, but might make proving your innocence more difficult when discovered and brought to daylight by opposition.

Answer (score 2):

When someone is holding a hostage they have some leverage over you. Providence is God. So if one's actions have the effect of giving God something that he can later use as leverage over you, you are giving hostages to Providence

Comment: I'd guessed as much, but how does that fit into the context? In what way is Black (or Tytlet's Dr Millar if you prefer) giving providence/Providence/God leverage over himself?

Comment: @Gilles- How about "*Black writes in his memoir that, while innocent of all charges, he regrets some aspects of his behaviour.*" which means that deep down he knows what he did was wrong even though they failed to prove it in court. And he regrets it because Providence might still hold him accountable on Judgement Day.

Comment: It's not at all a common usage ([hostage to **fortune**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hostage+to+fortune%2Chostage+to+providence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is *far* more common), but I'd have thought on average even native speakers would have more difficulty understanding *in the boldness of my muse* in OP's particular context.